# Error: Input contains NaN in sklearn python while converting categorical data into numeric

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

```
# Turn the Categories into Numbers

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

categorical_features = ["Make", "Colour", "Doors"]
one_hot = OneHotEncoder()
transformer = ColumnTransformer([("one_hot", one_hot, categorical_features)], remainder="passthrough")
transformed_X = transformer.fit_transform(X)
transformed_X
```

Comment: where is X coming from on your second to last line?  Is your code sample complete?

Comment: X = dataset.drop("target", axis=1)

Comment: Did you inspect the integrity of your dataset, and resulting X? I don't know what is supposed to be in your dataset but it seems you may have some empty values.